# Time Based SQL Injection attack affect all users or just me?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

Sorry for asking this silly question but If I found a website which is vulnerable to time base SQL Injection attack. For example I am using (sleep 20) means server will sleep for 20 seconds and then respond me so the server is down for 20 seconds only for me or all the users on website???

Comment: This sounds more like a question for security.stackexchange.com, although it would need improvement there too.

Comment: Okay I will ask this question on that platform.

Comment: For all will get 20 secs delay, as you said its website, how it delay for only for you ?

Comment: @AravindAravind have you heard of threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sleep() function affects only one *connection*.

It seems you misinterpret the Time Based SQL Injection confusing it with Denial of Service attack.

The primary goal of SQL injection is to compromise the system, not to put the server down. The delay in the time based injection is used for this exact purpose, to reveal some data, not to bring the server down. Though SQL injection can be used for the DoS attack too.

Comment: Don't know if we can call it a primary goal. SQL injection is just a way to make the system do your bidding. Data exfiltration may be most common given the entry point is a database but there can be opportunities for lateral movement. A very popular RDBMS used to (a long time ago) have shell command execution enabled by default using the usually high privileged service account. SQL injection attacks there easily let you own the box and easy access to other networked resources. RCE can cause harm beyond data in the database.